# Cron script runs fine but not updating Django database

Tags: python, django, sqlite, cron

I'm new in this field, and I am currently trying to get a python script to update a sqlite database (for django) every hour using cron.
Here is a cut down version of the script

```
import requests, sys, os, django, csv

sys.path.append("\var[...]\django")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "s.settings"
django.setup()

from health.models import s_model
import datetime
import logging

#################### initialising log file

today = datetime.datetime.now()
logging.basicConfig(filename="/var/[...]/processing.log", level=logging.INFO)
logging.info("\nScript run at " + str(today) + "\n")

################### getting data from csv and saving it to DB

with open('file.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    try:
        csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        i=0
        for row in csvreader:
            if(i>0):
                people = {}
                people['name'] = notNull(row[0].strip())
                people['age'] = notNull(row[1].strip())
                people = s_model(**people)
                people.save()
            i=i+1
    except Exception:
        logging.error("Error processing number for id "+ str(row["Id"]))
        return
```

And I have this file sitting in cron.hourly

```
#!/bin/bash
/var/[...]myfile.py
```

What I have checked:

- When I check on the django pages the data from the databases isn't updated.
- When I run the myfile.py manually from its folder, it runs fine and the database updates immediately.
- There is a newline at the end of the cron file.
- I've checked the permissions (both the cron.hourly file and the myfile.py file have +x permission, and are owned by root)
- When I check the log file (the one logged by the script), it tells me the script runs fine every hour and there were no errors.
- I have tried "sudo service apache2 restart" but the pages are still not updated.

Is there anything obvious I haven't checked? Any help or direction will be very much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: is your app inside a virtual environment?

Comment: Also, to prevent initializing the django environment, you could create you own manage.py command https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: @fixmycode I have done "pip -V" in the django folder and it tells me "pip 9.0.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg (python 2.7)" is this the correct way of checking for a virtual environment?

Comment: I was asking if your Django app was developed using a virtualenv

Comment: @SebCorbin thanks! I will give it a go when this issue is sorted (so I don't add further potential mistakes to the current problem!). Unless you think this is part of the issue?

Comment: @fixmycode I don't think so. I am not sure how to check this, when I google it it says to try "import sys
if hasattr(sys, 'real_prefix'): print "stuff"", but I get a syntax error when I put that in python

Answer (score 0):

Ok so the issues were fixed. Just putting it here in case anyone else runs into it.

1) There was a **sudo python** missing in front of the file location in the cron script. Now the code runs and updates the database.

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python /var/[...]myfile.py
```

2) And as a second issue, the csv file above **myfile.csv** should have been an absolute path (along with all the other paths in the script).